# Redis: Can items inside sets have expire times?

Tags: redis

Just as Redis keys can be 'expired', can individual items in sets be set to auto-expire?

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep it's not possible.

Solution was to add a key which expires every M seconds, and run a monitor service that cleans up the set every N seconds.